# block ip via htaccess require all denied not working at public_html

Tags: .htaccess, apache2.4

I have a file structure that look like this:

```
/public_html
  .htaccess
  index.php
  /country
    index.php
  /item
    index.php
```

in **.htaccess**:

```
<RequireAll>
Require all denied
Require ip 123.456.789.123
</RequireAll>
```

assume my ip is 123.456.789.123

But other user still able to access **index.php** at [www.example.com/country/](http://www.example.com/country/)

Previously all I need to do is change that one ip line but now I have to create .htaccess and add the above **RequireAll** command to every single folder, shown below:

```
/public_html
  .htaccess
  index.php
  /country
    .htaccess #extra 1
    index.php
  /item
    .htaccess #extra 2
    index.php
```

Would like to cut down that two extra .htaccess created

Also, all three .htaccess are 644 permission.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** At /public_html/.htaccess:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/country/'">
    Require all denied
    Require ip 123.456.789.123
</If>

<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/item/'">
    Require all denied
    Require ip 123.456.789.123
</If>
```

**2.** And delete both .htaccess located in /public_html/country and /public_html/item

**3.** If multiple countries, i.e:

```
/country/usa
/country/uk
```

then could use:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} ~ country$">
    Require all denied
    Require ip 123.456.789.123
</If>
```